# Input file upload inside ng-repeat not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, sharepoint-2013, ng-file-upload

I'm trying to add a file-upload control into a section (each cell of this section have different parameter). I use input file upload. But when i generate section with ng-repeat, it doesn't work at all, whereas when i make it outside of ng-repeat it works well.

Comment: Can someone tell me how to make this code ( following url https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_upload_file.htm) work on each row generated by ng-repeat ? if the html is something like this... <tbody ng-repeat="Item in Items">
<tr>
<td>
<input type = "file" file-model = "myFile"/>
<button ng-click = "uploadFile()">upload me</button>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

Comment: you need to show your code. So far I can only say that `ng-model` must be different for all of the inputs within `ng-repeat`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Can you modify the code in the url  to work on multiple rows. in each row i need a file upload control and simple input text box. tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_upload_file.htm

Comment: my guess is that your model now needs to be an array of models. e.g. `file-model="myFile"` be comes `file-model="myFiles[$index]"`, or (if they come from `ng-repeat`) `file-model="item"`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey i got your point.. but i'm new to angular.. so getting confused.. my current HTML is pasting below for reference. in controller i'm creating an array of objects for items as $scope.Items=[];

Comment: <table ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
<thead>
 <tr>                               
 <th>Item Title</th>                  
 <th>Action</th>
 </tr> 
</thead>
<tbody ng-repeat="Item in Items">
 <tr>
 <td>                 
 <span>{{Item.Title}}</span>
 <input type="text" ng-model="Item.Title"></input>               
 </td>
 <td colspan="1">
 <button type="button" ng-click="editItem(Item)">Edit</button>                   
 <button type="button" ng-click="saveItem(Item)">Save</button> 
 </td> 
 <tr>
</tbody>
</table>

Comment: @AlekseySolovey my HTML : textuploader.com/dz138 , My JS: textuploader.com/dz1ia ... my HTML is inside the xslt tr in sharepoint custom list edit form .. please see my html and js and suggest ..